# PowerBuilder - Copy Bitmap from the Clipboard

Tags: image, bitmap, copy, clipboard, powerbuilder

I want to copy bitmaps that are saved in the clipboard from i.e. Paint and such.

My code so far is as follows:

```
ulong l_handle, l_datasize, l_lock
long l_file
uint i_format
blob lb_blob
n_bitmap ln_bit

l_handle = handle(parent)
OpenClipboard(l_handle)
//2 = Bitmap
//8 = Bitmapinfo
if not IsClipboardFormatAvailable(8) then 
    closeclipboard()
    return
end if
l_handle = GetclipboardData( 8)

l_lock = GlobalLock(l_handle)
if not isnull(l_lock) then
    l_datasize = GlobalSize(l_lock)
    if l_datasize>0 then
        lb_blob = blob(space(l_datasize), EncodingAnsi!)
        ReadClipboardData(lb_blob, l_lock, l_datasize)
        GlobalUnlock(l_handle)
        closeClipboard()

        if not isnull(lb_blob) then
            //l_file = fileopen("c:\temp\test.dib", StreamMode!, Write!, LockReadWrite!, Replace!)

            ln_bit.of_writeblob( "c:\temp\test.bmp", lb_blob)
            ln_bit.of_writeblob( "c:\temp\test1.bmp", BlobMid(lb_blob, 15) )
            ln_bit.of_writeblob( "c:\temp\test2.bmp", BlobMid(lb_blob, 169))
            ln_bit.of_writeblob( "c:\temp\test3.bmp", BlobMid(lb_blob, 14))
            ln_bit.of_writeblob( "c:\temp\test4.bmp", BlobMid(lb_blob, 168))
            //FileWriteEx(l_file, lb_blob)

            //fileclose(l_file)
            //p_1.setpicture(lb_blob)
        end if
    end if
    GlobalUnlock(l_handle)
end if
closeClipboard()
```

External functions

```
Function Ulong GetClipboardData ( &
    uint uFormat&
    ) Library "user32.dll"
    Function boolean OpenClipboard ( &
    long hWndNewOwner &
    ) Library "user32.dll"

Function boolean CloseClipboard ( &
    ) Library "user32.dll"

Function ulong GlobalLock(&
  ulong hMem&
) Library "kernel32.dll"

Function boolean GlobalUnlock( ulong hMem) Library "kernel32.dll"

SUBROUTINE ReadClipboardData(ref blob Destination, ulong Source, ulong&
Length) Library "KERNEL32.DLL" Alias for "RtlMoveMemory"
FUNCTION ulong GlobalSize(ulong hMem) Library "kernel32.dll"
FUNCTION boolean IsClipboardFormatAvailable(ulong format) Library "user32.dll"
```

for GetclipboardData( ) I use the value 8 (Bitmapinfo), since 2 (Bitmap) always returns zero when calling the GlobalLock function.

So right now I am getting the Bitmapinfo in a Blob but am unable to save it.
It always says the image is damaged.
The reason I tried all this BlobMid stuff in the of_writeblob function was because I wanted to extract the bitmap out of the bitmapinfo (if that is even possible).

Here "http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_bitmap.html" they are creating a bitmapinfo and the blobheader has a length of 14, so I thought that it might work that way, but the file is still damaged. I guess the info does only contain information and not the actual bitmap.

Did anybody ever solve this, or is there a dll I can simply use?

Edit: in the topwiz sample they are creating a full bitmap with the header, the info and the actual bitmap, so my attempt could only fail I guess. 
So the mainproblem is, why is the Globallock function returning zero when call getclipboarddata with the parameter 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured some more stuff out if anyone is interested.
First you don´t have to call GlobalLock with bitmaps since it already gives you the handle to the HBitmap. Although working with that handle also resolves in a damaged file (and crash when calling globalsize).
I also tried adding the header and the bitmapinfo alongside the blob from hbitmap together but also resulted in a damaged file.

What I did now is I created a .dll in c++(visual studio) and I call that function in pfc_messagerouter.
Here you can download a little sample:
[Download](http://workupload.com/file/8sF2Pf6)

(the Bitmap file is saved under c:\temp\test.bmp, you can change it in the clicked Event of the Button)